# Symfony 4 : get the error message from count constraint applied on collection type

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

I am using a collection type of symfony 4, and i wish to apply a count constraint to this collection.

I have followed this tutorial : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

My idea is to apply the constraint directly on the collection :

```
$builder
    ->add('tags', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => Tag::class,
        'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\Count(['min' => 1, 'max' => 3])
        ]
    ])
;
```

But this does not work : I do not get any error message...

I have also try to use this constraint directly in the entity `Task`, without success.

So how can I get the error message from count constraint applied on collection type ?

Comment: You are also supposed to add the `NotNull` validator to check if this wasn’t empty. This is by design.

Comment: But how can I test if I only want three tags for this collection ?

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand your question.

Comment: I mean with the `NotNull` constraint I can test if there is at least one `Tag` in the collection. But how can I set a limit? I want to avoid the user to put to many `Tag`s.

Comment: Dude, I meant put both constraints. The NotNull / NotBlank constraints act as the “is required” property on the validator level. By design all Symfony constraints are “optional”.

Comment: Yes, I have already gotten this (your previous explanation was clear enough). But how can I set a maximum ?

Comment: With NotNull you tell the validator the field cannot be empty. Using the Count validator you limit the collection’s size (using the min/max or both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @emix said in comment

> With NotNull you tell the validator the field cannot be empty. Using the Count validator you limit the collection’s size (using the min/max or both)

And to print the error I set the parameter `error_bubbling` to `false` of the `CollectionType`.